# Displaying Category Type in Search Results Tag Pair

Tags: search

How do you output category info within the:

> {exp:search:search_results}

tag pair?

In my case I want to display the category name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just about all the variables available in the channel:entries tag pair are available in search results as well - have you tried just using the [categories tag pair](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#categories)?